# How to stop links from resizing my images?

Tags: html, css

I want my images to be links, but when I put them inside `<a>` tags, it shrinks a bit, which I wouldn't like to happen.

**My code:**

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.partner{
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.partner img{
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 65% !important;
}

.col-3 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <div class="col-3 partner"><a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/0yfcru3fnv591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3efaa93538888a691b5aec48e625808a054723a7" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="col-3 partner"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/k17jbglh6w591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=6d67b3f089bf5ade00aed2e870ba85a3cca8c192" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-3 partner"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/otg0pq6ywt591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a44deb1f27a510ee6957d780c204e6827b401012" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-3 partner"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/03yhd14gbs591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=263ed6ecf41d50d51b8c6f6fa84923b0a0d57180" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

As you see I currently don't have any styling for `a`, but I have tried some, `display: inline-block;` didn't work in any context, and setting `all: none;` or `all: inherit;` on `a` also did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `.partner a` to have similar properties as `.partner` as the `a` tag wouldn't have properties such as `display: flex`, then you need to create the same selector as `.partner img` but inside that `a` tag, so `.partner a img`.

I think, in general, the better approach is to put every image inside the `a` tag, and just disable the linking for the images that do not link to anywhere for less code duplication.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.partner {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.partner img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 65% !important;
}

.partner a {
  all: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

.partner a img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 65% !important;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-3 partner">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/0yfcru3fnv591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3efaa93538888a691b5aec48e625808a054723a7" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 partner"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/k17jbglh6w591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=6d67b3f089bf5ade00aed2e870ba85a3cca8c192" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-3 partner"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/otg0pq6ywt591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a44deb1f27a510ee6957d780c204e6827b401012" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-3 partner"><img src="https://preview.redd.it/03yhd14gbs591.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=263ed6ecf41d50d51b8c6f6fa84923b0a0d57180" alt=""></div>
</div>
```